# unable to get the node using xpath which reads the desired ID from the input

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xslt-1.0

I am trying to get the value of an attribute of an xml node by dynamically creating the xpath. But it is returning empty value all the time. If I hard-code the xpath, it works fine. Below is a sample xml file:

```
<root>  
<PR id="id6016" name="OUTER WORLD">
    <ADS id="id6017" dsRef="#id15" role="form1">
    </ADS>
    <ADS id="id6018" dsRef="#id9" role="form1">
    </ADS>
</PR>

<PR id="id1000" name="OUTER WORLD">
    <ADS id="id1001" dsRef="#id16" role="form1">
    </ADS>
    <ADS id="id1002" dsRef="#id10" role="form1">
    </ADS>
</PR>

<DS id="id9" name="form1" version="7" type="CAD">
</DS>

<DS id="id15" name="form1" version="1" type="MSWord">
</DS>

<DS id="id10" name="form1" version="1" type="CAD">
</DS>

<DS id="id16" name="form1" version="1" type="MSWord">
</DS>

</root>
```

My sample xsl is:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="no" indent="no" encoding="utf-8"/>
  <xsl:template match="/root">
    <result>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="PR" mode="PR" />
    </result>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="PR" mode="PR">
    <PR>
      <xsl:attribute name="id">
        <xsl:value-of select="@id" />
      </xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:attribute name="name">
        <xsl:value-of select="@name" />
      </xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:for-each select="ADS[@role='form1']">
        <DS>
          <xsl:attribute name="id">
            <xsl:value-of select="string(substring-after(@dsRef, '#'))" />
          </xsl:attribute>
          <xsl:value-of select="../DS[@id=string(substring-after(@dsRef, '#'))]/@type" />
        </DS>           

      </xsl:for-each>
      <DS2>
        <xsl:value-of select="../DS[@id='id9']/@type" />
      </DS2>      
      <DS3>
        <xsl:value-of select="../DS[@id=string(substring-after(@dsRef, '#'))]/@type" />
      </DS3>

    </PR>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

As you can see I get any innertext for DS2 tag but not for DS or DS3. I have also added the id attribute to DS tag to show that the id I am getting is good.

Ultimately I want to filter DS tags that have the type="CAD" and store it's id in a variable but right now I am unable to get the xml node using xpath so I am stuck.

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood your description of your problem correctly, the instruction

```
<xsl:value-of select="../DS[@id='id9']/@type" />
```

in the DS2 element is producing the expected and desired value, but the instruction

```
<xsl:value-of select="../DS[@id=string(substring-after(@dsRef, '#'))]/@type" />
```

in the DS3 element is not.  And similarly, the @id attribute on the DS element being generated within your xsl:for-each is carrying the expected value, but the element content is not as expected.  (Pro tip: You will have better luck eliciting answers to questions on Stack Overflow if it's not quite such a chore to understand how what you are getting differs from what you expected and wanted.)

You have two problems here.

First, the reference to `@dsRef` succeeds in the first xsl:value-of of xsl:for-each, because the context element for that attribute reference is the ADS element which carries the `dsRef` element.  The reference to `@dsRef` in the second xsl:value-of of the xsl:for-each fails, because it's inside a predicate, and the context element is the DS element on which the predicate is being tested.  The reference to `@dsRef` in the DS3 debugging element is similarly a reference to a non-existing 'dsRef' attribute on a DS element.

There are two ways to solve this problem.  You can read up on `current()`, which among other things is a way of pointing from within a predicate to the context element for the entire XPath expression, and rewrite the attribute reference as something like `current()/@dsRef`.  Many people would recommend this path.

Or you can avoid having to learn about `current()` and exactly how many steps up the stack of context nodes it climbs at any given point, and bind the value you want to a variable to which you can refer in your expression.  (I know from experience that it is possible to spend years writing XSLT programs and never need to understand all the fiddly details of `current()`.)  Your for-each would in this case look something like this:

```
<xsl:for-each select="ADS[@role='form1']">
  <xsl:variable name="targetDS" select="substring-after(@dsRef,'#')"/>
  <DS>
    <xsl:attribute name="id">
      <xsl:value-of select="$targetDS" />
    </xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:value-of select="../DS[@id=$targetDS]/@type" />
  </DS>           
</xsl:for-each>
```

You may find (as I do) that having the target ID in a named variable makes it easier to understand what the two value-of instructions are doing.

After this change, however, your program still does not work.

Your second problem is that you are looking for DS elements among the siblings of the current ADS element, but no ADS element in your input actually has a DS sibling; they are all siblings of PR.  If the 'id' attributes on your elements behave as XML IDs, then the hierarchical location of the element is immaterial, and a simpler expression like

```
//DS[@id=$targetDS]
```

would be more resilient (and clearer).  If you have a DTD and the 'id' attributes are declared as having type ID, it is even simpler to write

```
id($targetDS)
```

which means 'the element whose ID is $targetDS'.  If for some reason you really want to restrict the expression to DS elements in a particular area of the input document, you need to be sure to refer to that area correctly.  After I replaced the `..` with `../..`, the stylesheet produced what I believe are the expected results.

Comment: thanks for your explanation. I haven't used the current() function but i will look into using it more often in my code. The xml I shared above is only a snippet and unfortunately the original xml doesn't contain a DTD to define the ID. I am not sure I follow your solution of replacing .. with ../.. when i hard-code the id9 in the xpath, I get the value of the type attribute but not when I use a variable.

Comment: Your two debugging elements DS2 and DS3 are outside the for-each:  the context node is PR, not ADS.  If you move them into the for-each so the context node is an ADS element, you will see that both fail.